# Make observable to behave like promise in RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex

Considering I have a function which calls a server and returns user data through Observable:

```typescript
getUserById (id: number): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get('/users/' + id)
    .map(response => response.json())
  ;
}
```

**How do I make it to behave more like a Promise?**

The problem is, that the request won't be made until someone subscribes to the returned observable. Also, when multiple subscriptions are done, the server will be called multiple times.

What I want is:

- To call server as soon as `getUserById()` is called (the subscription should be optional, only if caller really wants to obtain the returned value or cares to know when request is complete)
- Multiple subscriptions should not spawn multiple requests, but should return the same value obtained from the server

With this approach I will be able to make this function work:

```typescript
refreshUser (): Observable<User> {
  return repository.getUserById(this.currentUser.id)
    .map(user => this.currentUser = user)
  ;
}
```

When calling `refreshUser()` the request should be made and `this.currentUser = user` should be evaluated. If I want, I can subscribe to the returned observable in order to obtain fresh data, e.g:

```typescript
// Just refreshes the current user
refreshUser();

// Refreshes the current user and obtains fresh data
refreshUser().subscribe(user => console.log('Refreshed user', user));
```

I've tried to use `publish()`, `refCount()` and `share()` in different combination, but it only helps with the first requirement (i.e. avoiding multiple calls to the server), but how do I make the original observable hot?

---

## Update

After further investigation with different options it seems like solution with making `getUserById()` hot will not solve it, because I have two mapping functions on different levels (one in `getUserById()` and one in `refreshUser()`) and I need both of them to execute. In order to solve this, I need to somehow "push" the observable from bottom to top. And it looks like it will require a lot of boilerplate code for each level.

In promises it will look pretty simple:

```typescript
getUserById (id: number): Promise<User> {
  return this.http.get('/users/' + id)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .toPromise()
  ;
}
```

```typescript
refreshUser (): Promise<User> {
  return repository.getUserById(this.currentUser.id)
    .then(user => {
      this.currentUser = user;
      return user;
    })
  ;
}
```

Is there a simpler solution with RxJS or Promises are actually better suited for the job?

Comment: Easy but dirty: Before returning the observable, subscribe to it in the service.

Comment: I don't understand. If you only use `getUserById` through `refreshUser` that should always make another request. Why do you want `getUserById` hot?

Answer (score 4):

From your description it looks like you could do something like this:

```
getUserById (id: number): Observable<User> {
  const observable = this.http.get('/users/' + id)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .publishReplay(1)
    .refCount()
    .take(1);

  observable.subscribe();
  return observable;
}
```

If you subscribe to the same Observable returned from `getUserById` multiple times you'll always get the same result.

Comment: "To call server as soon as getUserById() is called". `refCount` doesn't make it so

Comment: It's not even supposed to. That's not the reason it's used here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will need to use a or `Subject` or a `BehaviorSubject` instead of just a normal Oberservable. In your case, a `BehaviorSubject` is better as it stores the current value.

Declare two variables, one being a normal `User` type, and the other one is a `BehaviorSubject` of `User`:

```
currentUser:User;
userBSubject:BehaviorSubject<User>;
```

Because you will need an initial value for the `BehaviorSubject`, you can initialize it at your constructor:

```
constructor(){
  this.userBSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(this.currentUser)
}
```

So here is where the magic comes in. Every time you need to modify (in your case, "refresh") the data, you will call the method `.next()`:

```
refreshUser() {
    return repository.getUserById(this.currentUser.id)
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.userBSubject.next(user);
        return this.userBSubject.asObservables()
      });
}
```

Then you can do:

```
// Just refreshes the current user
refreshUser();

// Refreshes the current user and obtains fresh data
refreshUser().subscribe(user => console.log('Refreshed user', user));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Using one of of "Subjects" looks like an only viable option at this point, however, I find it too complicated and cumbersome. I'm trying to make my communication layer as slim as possible. After spending the time trying to figure this out I realized that promises are actually much better suitable for this problem (and promise-based solution is getting much leaner and universal). I think I will stick with it for now.